are those changes to earth's atmosphere viable? could something else be better?
(Edit 26.12 due to lack of clarity)
Okay, so I've been trying to figure out the mechanics for a thing I'm writing, or more so planning to.
It is supposed to be earth in years in the future. I'm not married to a specific time yet since it's dependant on what specifically happens for the plot to be possible.
The key thing is that the air has been polluted enough for humans to not be able to breathe it again and the changes are several enough for it to be a problem that cannot be fixed by simply 'waiting it out'.
My current that my head has latched onto is poor Coral reefs dying out in a circumstance of us not being able to fix the issues in time. I am roughly predicting that with the 50% of oxygen produced by them and possible panic that perspective would cause over the years, there would be attempts to fix it and produce more oxygen through other ways so most likely it wouldn't be a 50% loss — but rather a 20% something and rest produced artificially and by forests.
Now. My goals for this is again, humans (and other species by proxy) not being able to live under normal air, requiring them to adapt in other ways and acclimatisation not an option so the change must be bigger than that.
Additionally to this, I want the CO2 levels to rise. I admittedly have no idea how high/low i can realisticakky do it though specific numbers up to a 0.00001 aren't necessary. I was thinking something even as drastic as 03% or more of it, sort of replacing the Oxygen in part since there wouldn't be enough stuff to convert it to Oxygen. Right?
To that i was considering a catastrophic eventually, maybe an underwater eruption or some other thing that would make things just worse. Tinkering with the actual underground storage of CO2 also crossed my mind, however as everyone probably already figured out, I am not well versed. This is a start of probably very long rabbit hole.
What I assumed would happen in this scenario is, again, oxygen levels taking a leaf to much worse levels, alongside CO2 levels rising which also is pretty bad... adding to that a rise, perhaps slight or bigger, of Nitrogen because well, humans would want to grow more plants, right? So they would possibly produce more fertilizers, which could then also polluted the waters - preferably oceans. Which i imagine would make it worse as well (better for me and my poor glued together plot).
I hope that edit helps since some people seemed upset about my lack of ability to voice it all properly.
I will also add that the thing that must change is strictly the enviorment. It's a crucial part of the plot and midifications to humans themselves would not work as intended. I suppose it doesn't have to be steictly an oxygen/CO2 issue, though thats what I started with.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Done, i hope it's better now?

"Coral reefs dying"..."with the 50% of oxygen produced by them": coral reefs do not produce 50% of oxygen. All marine life taken together accounts for a bit less than that, and that's almost entirely phytoplankton.

This is a bit of a Frame Challenge, but I think it's important
It seems to me you're putting the cart before the horse. Whatever your introduced mechanic is, that's what will change the atmosphere. You might discover you'll have a hard time rationalizing the mechanic if you pick the quality of the atmosphere first. In fact, some of your numbers don't make sense.
Let's start with the "normal" atmosphere: 78% N2, 21% O2, 0.9% Ar, 0.04% CO2 and 0.06% a bunch of other stuff that doesn't matter enough for this discussion.
We already have a problem with your 79% N2 number. An increase in the planetary atmosphere of 1% is a big deal. Where's the extra N2 coming from? Humanity can do (and does) a great deal to screw up the Nitrogen Cycle, but to increase the atmospheric percentage? It's worth taking a peek at the Nitrogen Cycle to understand more about it. But the fact that you increased the number tells me you're kinda guessing as to how the atmosphere works.
Let's consider a basic example
Let's say we're only focused on too many combustion engines. They produce a lot of ugly and while CO2 is at the top of that list quantity-wise, it's not necessarily the biggest offender of human life. But let's roll with it, because it's the easiest to work with for this example.
Unless you're sending something into the atmosphere that will bind with existing chemicals (actually not as easy as it sounds, but it does happen), all you're doing is adding a new compound to the atmosphere. That will lower all of the above percentages because the change you're adding won't move the total percentage above 100%.
You've suggested an increase of CO2 to 0.3%. As @Elemtilas has mentioned, that's a pretty big deal. The Earth (and, notably, humans... I'll get to that in a moment) is pretty sensitive to the amount of CO2 in the atmosphere. But, what does that increase mean?
The reality is that unless we dig really deep into some nasty chemistry, all the gasses originally in the atmosphere are still there. What we're doing is recalculating the percentages of 100% representing all the pieces. This is actually an algebra problem.
Let's consider a first-estimate. You can think of the original atmosphere as this:
78/100 N2, 21/100 O2, 0.9/100 Ar, 0.04/100 CO2 and 0.06/100 trace gases.
Changing CO2 does this:
78/100.26 N2, 21/100.26 O2, 0.9/100.26 Ar, 0.3/100.26 CO2 and 0.06/100.26 trace gasses.
Giving us...
77.8% N2, 20.9% O2, 0.9% Ar, 0.3% CO2 and 0.06% trace gases.
You could get a smidgen more accurate than this by forcing the result of CO2 to be exactly 0.3% (rather than the 0.299% the above actually gives you), but it won't change the other numbers enough to matter.
What does this mean?
First, it means that the Earth (and humanity!) is really sensitive to CO2. Humanity more than the Earth. As mentioned, I'll get to that later. Little changes matter.
Next, if you want to change the atmosphere as you've described, you'll be talking about a really exotic change. As in, "a giant ball of Nitrogen ice fell into the ocean and when it melted: a lot of fish died, a lot of algae proliferated, and the atmosphere received an increase in N2."
Significantly lowering O2 is almost as hard to rationalize. The O2 must go somewhere. One could say that the car exhaust is converting O2 into CO2. That's true! But plants really like CO2 and happily convert it back to O2 and return the carbon into the soil. If cars were producing so much CO2 that it was overwhelming all the plant life on the planet (Most people don't really comprehend the size of this beautiful place we call home.) then the other byproducts of combustion (CO and uncombusted hydrocarbons, for example) would have caused humanity problems before we got there.
But would this still allow life?
Of course. It's really hard to kill the Earth. Remember, plants like CO2! I apologize for getting on my soap box for a moment, but most environmental activists worry about the planet... which is nonsensical. The Earth created life amidst a LOT worse conditions than humanity's created. Kill all the humans and the Earth will happily chug along and create more life. It's what it does. Honestly, if we unleashed all the nuclear weapons and pollutants we could possibly release all at once, it wouldn't kill the Earth. On the timescale of life, it wouldn't even be a bump in the road.
The problem is saving the humans.
Let me state as I step down from my soap box that any environmental activist who doesn't have as their core belief and message, "we're trying to save the Earth for our grandchildren...," they're being dishonest about the problem. OK, soap box mode off. Thanks for listening.
Where does this leave you?
Don't start by modifying the atmosphere. As I've pointed out, it's easy to create an atmosphere that's really hard to rationalize, regardless of whether or not it can sustain life. Start, instead, with the mechanic that will change the atmosphere. Figure out what that mechanic will add (add!) to the atmosphere. Once you know that, you can recalculate the percentages and produce a very realistic consequence that's easy to defend.
And, yes, it doesn't take much to ruin the party for everybody.

I read the comments and I yea. I was just guessing as to what it could be (im no expert. This is the very start of my big wondering and really I'm balling it as it goes...) – I changed most of those % because I thought that 'well, if we're in creasing A then B must go down 'nd, yea. I honestly don't know how I wanted to rationalize that N2 going up.
My gnrl idea was that basically humanity polluted the env and then something erupted/fell to kick a dying horse. But would you have any suggestions as to what to add to the atmosphere to get that? Im not planning to hurt the earth, just humans.

"they're being dishonest about the problem." Or they're confused, which I suspect is far more common.

@JohnDallman Fair enough... I'm just reacting to (and I'm being serious) 50 years of environmentalists claiming, "irreversible climate change in the next X years!" But you're without a doubt correct. Such statements had and continue to have more to do with not really understanding the planet than it is about dishonesty. Well, except for climategate, but we'll let that one slide as there was plenty of stupidity on both sides.

@colrel You haven't given us enough information about your goals to give you any clear advice. Do you have a preferred solution type? How fast must it occur? What specific consequences are you looking for? Etc. To give you an example, alas... non-atmospheric, but a great example of how we can completely screw ourselves, consider reading the article The Lawyer Who Became DuPont’s Worst Nightmare or seeing the movie Dark Waters. ...

... The gist of the issue is that DuPont invented Teflon during WWII and then discovered it'd make a great coating for frying pans. What they didn't tell anyone is that it created a chemical byproduct that cannot be broken down naturally and is whomping hard to break down outside a fission/fusion reaction. They scattered it everywhere to hide it. It causes cancer. If I remember the film correctly, something like 95% of the Earth (the entire planet) has been touched by the chemical and 99% of all animal life (including humans) have it permanently in their bodies. ...

... But if you're married to atmospheric problems, start with the major pollutants we're dealing with and then work from there. The first item on the list, PM2.5, is a whopper. I live in Montana and the state is now forced by the Feds to test for PM2.5 particulates on the order of a few parts per trillion. I didn't even know they could measure the problem that precisely. Nor did I know it was that big a deal. Fair warning: this is a pretty deep rabbit hole. Try to keep it simple. Cheers.

I'll look it all over. Thanks again! I've edited the main post and I hope its all more clear now. The numbers I gave before weren't a sure thing anyway. I just found a spead sheet online that was supposed to help with planning things out but I realise now that I can't really use it if I don't know what exactly happened so tou were right. I have some ideas and will gibe th thing you sent a read.

Not Tonight Dear, I Have a Headache

So, 0.3% CO2 seems to be in the headache, fatigue, loss of focus range according to the Gas Measurement Specialists at co2meter.com. Seems to be the sweet spot between drowsiness and toxicity. They say that concentrations as high as 3% are dangerous. You're nowhere close, so yes, habitable. Vulcanologists concur: you can remain alive at up to perhaps 7%, but much above that and you'll be looking at death.

On the other hand, botanists might be having difficulty determining if their heavy breathing is due to CO2 levels, or excitement over the increases in plant respiration that will occur as CO2 levels rise in the atmosphere.
